# Bad quality or wrong answers on Android

Tags: discussion, questions, answer-quality

I am currently developing Android apps. I use Stack Overflow every time I can't find a solution. Sadly, after gaining a bit of experience on my subject it's clear that there are too many ***wrong*** answers or answers containing bad practices out there.

Because of the Android development community is (still) on it's early stages, wrong answers propagate really easily. This leads more bad answers and poor performing apps. This might even affect Google's standing on the market (which is not necessarily bad).

Down voting is not a real solution because people are coming here to find a quick fix, if an answer is accepted then nobody cares the score. Even if it's from 2012 they don't care. I saw a lot of deprecated methods on decompiled apps from some big companies.

Also there is not enough people to answer every question correctly.

What can we do about this?

Comment: What makes you think users don't care about the answer's score? What makes you think companies relying on deprecated methods in their code base is related to answer quality on SO? Do you have an example of such a wrong answer?

Comment: I think you are essentially asking: "why does everyone and their mother, with little to no programming experience, think that they should be developing apps". There's this huge app hype which is still going strong, which in turn generates floods of useless and/or poor quality apps. It has a lot in common with the Internet hype around year 2000, when everyone and their mother made web pages. What can you do about it? Nothing, most likely. Mankind is far too dumb to detect and ignore bloated market hypes.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You can understand a code if it's copied from Stack Overflow, like if variable names, calling order etc. are same. And as you requested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615113/ All of the answers are bad practices.

Comment: As a fellow Android developer, what do you think about the good practice for that question? You can answer it, and as time goes by, and if people agree with it, the answer will naturally goes up by upvote. As for *people are coming here to find a quick fix, ignoring most upvoted answer because there is an accepted answer*, then that's their fault. Really.

Comment: @AndrewT., yes it's their fault. But it's costing us. Most people think "Android is slow." Moreover Android development is the second child after iOS, at least at where I live. Bad practices, non optimized algorithms makes people frustrated. What I mean is developer's stupidity and arrogance makes us, Android developers, less effective on mobile market.

Comment: If the ratio of knowledgeable to inexperienced users is too low in a certain area then voting will not result in a clear separation of high quality answers and less useful answers. Can I trust the upvotes there now to really indicate high quality answers?

Comment: @interlude I'd happily allow people to think Android development is slow, knowing I can do it quicker makes me worth more, but that is besides the point. This is an issue on all tags where best practices change / frameworks are improved. Just vote down and answer the question with the correct/up-to-date way, the community will take care of the rest for you.

Comment: Leave comments and encourage authors to improve, a lot of them revise their answers eventually after getting a comment. Then again, sometimes [I'm a bit blunt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554270/how-to-configure-angular-resource-ngresource-to-pull-data-from-another-domain#comment36381460_16554586)

Comment: Another example - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18392440/1348195

Comment: How about when you see a question with a bunch of terrible answers, you add a better answer yourself? If the existing answers demonstrate bad practise then explain why in your answer. Over time the better answer would be up voted and the problem would be solved. I agree though that the quality of questions and answers in Android is dire.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I agree users would generally care about the answer's score, but they might not be able to see that there is controversy, if their reputation [is too low to see the scoring details](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141390/148833). For example, an answer with +10 and -7 would show as +3 (although there would probably be a few comments in this case).

Comment: "Another example - stackoverflow.com/a/18392440/1348195" at least 25 upvotes for an answer that never works. Seems crazy.

Comment: So many comments here use the term "over time" -- over time, with Android, the answers change. New best practices come about. APIs become deprecated. The shift in versions causes a shift in how you can do things (truly no need to support API4 anymore, for example). And so on. The sheer number of Android questions to participants is too overwhelming. When accepted answers have +2 and bad answers have +1, after years, there's no telling for the new Android developer, especially when the "+1" one says has a comment by someone saying "this is the real right answer."

Comment: As an example, I recently searched on a topic and found probably 50 near-duplicate questions, with few to no answers, almost no accepted answers, and dates ranging from 2010 to current. Most of the answer attempts were bordering on downright rude or insulting (not on purpose, necessarily) given what I ultimately learned. Some of the accepted answers weren't answering the real problem, but rather some beginner mistakes -- the real problem remained. Seriously, is this a hopeless situation?

Comment: 100% agree with @interlude

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few things you can be doing, and they're pretty basic instructions:

1. Downvote the crap.  You have the necessary 125 rep, I promise the -1 hit is nothing in the long run.
2. Refute wrong answers.  If they erred, call it out in the comments.  Astute comments always attract votes.
3. Flag it.  This doesn't help with merely incorrect answers, but it's a great tool when appropriate.
4. Upvote good answers.  Obviously, good answers always need to be rewarded.
5. Add your own answers.  Even if a question is dated, someone somewhere will benefit someday.
6. Review popular questions.  The best or even correct answer may be missing; the traffic on these questions will ensure that your contribution will be worthwhile.

This doesn't address the cultural concerns you've raised, and honestly you seem to be a little too caught up in that.  It concerns me that the people I see complaining about this here are longtime users with almost no down votes, zero flags, and merely a handful of answers.  We're grateful for what you have done, but you could be doing more.

You have the power to contribute, go use it.

Comment: Problem is, from my experience with SO, there's this thing about not changing old, accepted answers. Questions get locked, protected, etc. An absolutely correct answer in 2010 might have been updated in 2012 with a new correct answer, then protected or locked because that new answer got all the votes, the accepted answer is "wrong" (deprecated) and now in 2014, it's all deprecated, but has been locked or protected for years. The relative speed of change vs the time it takes for updated answers to get the good votes is too long, and old bad answers can still solve problems, even if incorrectly.

Comment: @lilbyrdie I see you have 8 down votes and 18 answers over 5 years.  Interlude has 10 down votes and 16 answers over 2 years.  I have no sympathy for users who are going to bemoan how bad the quality is when they're not even using their basic privileges.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311425) is another example that shows how the wizdom of the crowd not necessarily works well. These answers were never correct; sometimes, they happen to work (because Google did poor job of defining this API), and what happens is that people try the solution on their device, happily click "⬆︎" and forget about this; later they probably have to spend a while to resolve the situations when this does not work for somebody on the other side of the planet, but there is no incentive for them to go back and downvote the answer that caused this.

Comment: I just learned question downvotes are free. That matters since poor/duplicate Android questions are part of the problem. See
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/ and 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down