# What should be done about the recycling of incorrect answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm not going to point fingers, but I will hint with links to answers.

1. [Is there a way on Android to intercept incoming calls/SMSes to either block/unblock it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406867/is-there-any-way-to-intercept-incoming-calls-sms-to-either-block-unblock-it-an/24630564#24630564)
2. [How to prevent SMS going to inbox in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175969/how-to-prevent-sms-going-to-inbox-in-android/24630501#24630501)
3. [How to block all incoming calls and text messages in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22069017/how-to-block-all-incoming-calls-and-text-messages-in-android-programmatically/24630427#24630427)
4. [Marking SMS messages as read/unread or deleting messages not working in KitKat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158998/marking-deleting-message-doesnot-work-in-android-kitkat/24630286#24630286)
5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785284/can-we-able-to-delete-incoming-sms-from-sms-inbox-in-kitkat-version/24630201#24630201

All the answers posted are more or less the same thing.

> Currently existing SMS cannot be deleted from KitKat version by 3rd party apps.

That is incorrect. On Android 4.4 (Kitkat), only one app, the app that is set as the default (can be 3rd party), can receive the new SMS_DELIVER_ACTION intent. From this intent, you can then have the option to consume (delete from the SMS inbox).

> Moreover you can cancel all incoming SMS to be stored in inbox. To do this you you need to study SMS broadcast receiver.

That is only true for android versions below 4.3. Which is not what most questions are asking about (note the kitkat in the titles).

I believe recycling answers is the bad alternative to closing as a duplicate. I have already raised a flag and let a lot of time pass (1 week).

> [image]

This gets to me because a few weeks ago I was searching for answers and I kept looking at this user's incorrect and recycled answer over and over. I know that an answer shouldn't be removed because it's wrong (downvote is what's appropriate), but when it's duplicated like this.

Should something be done or ...?

---

I don't think this question is a duplicate of [How to handle historical, highly upvoted but completely incorrect answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255198/how-to-handle-historical-highly-upvoted-but-completely-incorrect-answers). If you check out the answers linked in my question, you can see that all of them were not accepted, and were not upvoted (except for one).

Comment: [This looks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158998/marking-deleting-message-doesnot-work-in-android-kitkat) like the best duplicate target.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If the questions are duplicates, pick one target and point the rest there, and if the answer is incorrect and you're able to debunk it, post an answer to the target question.

As you may have guessed, we don't delete incorrect answers, but if someone is bumping several questions with what is essentially the same answer when they should be flagging the questions as duplicates instead, we may speak to them.

On a side note, when a user copies and pastes the same answer verbatim across multiple questions, the answers will be automatically flagged. In this case the answers weren't *exact* copies, so they were not flagged. Thanks for bringing them to our attention.