# When a question is teeming with out of date answers

Tags: discussion, old-questions, old-answers

[This massively upvoted Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill?answertab=votes#tab-top) is a complete mess/really hard to use; I rarely see questions that run to 3 pages of answers but in this particular case it seems that a considerable number of those answers are hacks or poor quality workarounds that no longer work, or worse, a duplicate of a low quality workaround (that no longer works)..

Some of these answers have high upvote counts too, so it seems a really hard thing to fight with the usual DV/comment route. If there were a few answers, commenting "doesn't work" might help find one that does, but there are so many answers on this Q, that it even gets hard to find those that have been commented as non-workers

I read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255198/how-to-handle-historical-highly-upvoted-but-completely-incorrect-answers) that I TL;DR'd as "nothing can be done" - is this still the case? No good mechanism for dealing with questions of this ilk?

Comment: What are the problems caused by the existing answers?  Ask a new question that states, in the question, that you're using [the workaround you don't like] and it's causing [this problem], and they're looking for a solution that doesn't have that negative side effect.  You can then post an answer that doesn't have [this problem].  You can then direct people to the new question, rather than that one, when you see others with the problem in the future.

Comment: It's off-topic, so I voted to close it.  Not that it will do any good.

Comment: @MartinJames How is that question off topic? And with the flag for **general computing hardware and software**?

Comment: @MartinJames, I think you've misinterpreted the question (not this one, the one you are trying to close)

Comment: There have been discussions about sorting by recent votes and removing the accepted answer from it's top position after a certain date. That would mitigate these issues. Unfortunately, these suggestions have not _(yet?)_ been implemented.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Even if they were, the problem in this case is that the bad answers are the ones continuing to attract votes.  There's not much to do from a technical standpoint when everyone is indicating that a bad answer is a good answer (if they are indeed bad answers, I don't know enough to know).

Comment: Those comments are a mess though - works, doesn't work, works, doesn't work, etc.

Comment: Easy fix, just cast -2 rep on user who upvote a bad solution.

Comment: @TGrif I don't think that you should do that, no.

Comment: if 5 people vote to close & 7 (?) people vote to delete, then the question is done.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Even when the question is protected?

Comment: @TGrif I don't think it prevents deletion (but any user >15k rep can unprotect). It's just to prevent new users to answer.

Comment: I think the thing that I didn't point out clearly enough in my question here is that there are 3 pages of answers *that predominantly have comments to the effect that they no longer work*.. As such it's not a good reseource to have on SO, if SO is modelling a dictionary of problems and good solutions; the problem is still a problem, but the solutions are not standing up to the shifting sands of time

Comment: Would stripping *all* the upvotes of the existing answers, so that the old ones (upvoted hundreds of times, but now no longer work) can instead sink? The question remains valid, but there needs to be some deprecation method for answers that still trade on their old upvote count (you'd think that people would be more likely to DV something that didn't work than UV something that did [hence this process would be natural], but seems not?)

Answer (score -2):

How about:

1. Post a new question asking for an up-to-date solution, possibly as Community Wiki.
2. Close the original one as a duplicate, with a big note that the answers there are outdated.
3. Profit?

Comment: And repeat the process when the new question gets to the same condition? And what about the existing answers? Are they all equally out-of-date and useless? IMO, this proposes a new problem instead of a solution. (Not that I think there is any reasonable way to "solve" this).