# Potential issues with an old, well upvoted wiki answer. Delete, edit, or leave?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261158/2632129

Anyone with solid PHP knowledge should see the problem immediately. The question is about solving the issue of getting PHP "Undefined" notices, but every suggestion in the (above linked) answer introduces the very thing it should be striving to resolve.

Each suggestion from the answer:

1)

```
$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
if (empty($user_name)) $user_name = '';
```

If `$_SESSION['user_name']` is not set it'll create a PHP Notice.

2)

```
$user_name = '';
$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
```

There is no point of the first line as it's entirely overwritten on the next line.
If `$_SESSION['user_name']` is not set it'll create a PHP Notice.

3)

```
$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
if (!isset($user_name)) $user_name = '';
```

If `$_SESSION['user_name']` is not set it'll create a PHP Notice.

4)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

The question states `What do I need to do to fix them?`, the above suggestion does not fix the problem in the code, it simply stops the Notice from being logged. Surely the aim is to fix the code from being susceptible to producing PHP Notices, rather than hide them away.

I suggest that the following could replace all the above noted suggestions in the answer and caters for all the original intentions:

```
$user_name = isset($_SESSION['user_name']) ? $_SESSION['user_name'] : '';
```

However, the answer has 112 upvotes (only 9 down). While I don't in any way doubt my arguments, I thought it best to open up for discussion.

Should we delete the answer, leave it alone, or edit it to remove the above outlined incorrect suggestions?

Comment: Wrong answers should be downvoted. Wiki doesn't make it different.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255198/how-to-handle-historical-highly-upvoted-but-completely-incorrect-answers).

Comment: Being a community wiki, I'd say the easier path would be to just edit the problematic parts. And/or vote depending of what you think of the usefulness of the answer.

Comment: @BDL Removed the `isset` because I thought it was redundant. You can also accomplish the same some other ways (`array_key_exists`, `array_merge`, etc, etc;) but I see no reason in covering them all. But maybe you are right, and the other version should be edited back in.

Comment: @user202729 I don't believe this can be a duplicate of any other question a it's discussing specific content, not just the general idea of editing inaccurate wiki or upvoted answers. It's defo related though, thanks

Comment: why not `$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'] ?? ''` ??