# Make it harder for new users to post questions on SO

Tags: feature-request

Today me (and some others) spent whole day on "babysitting" some new user, which posted question after another, while never accepting a single answer (although he got lots of help), not providing enough information, posting additional questions in the comments and ending up completely ignoring the correct answers while keeping doing the same mistakes over and over on the following questions and so on.

I suggest that a new user will not be able to post a question until he accepts the following terms of agreement (this should be brought to him in a way that he can't just press "OK" and move on):

<s>1. You are obligated to accept a correct answer (saying "Thanks!!!" in comments isn't enough).</s>

2. Each question has to contain the following information before asked:

   2.1. An informative title

   2.2. A reproducible example

   2.3. A well defined question

   2.4. The desired output
3. Can't post more than 3 questions a day (untill will reach a certain amount of reputation)
4. (Additional terms which can't think of right now)

---

**Edit 12/24/2014:**

I can't delete this (because it has answers with positive score), though It seems that lately this question brings some new traffic again, so I deleted the first point as I currently disagree with it myself (though, frankly, I don't really care anymore).

Comment: They can only post a new question every 90 minutes. That's a maximum of 16 question a day, or 2 questions in 3 hours. Not enough?

Comment: _You are obligated to accept a correct answer_ No, you cannot state a user is obligated to accept anything.

Comment: @bluefeet, why not? Why are spending hours in this site in order to help people while all they do is just using this site for their own purposes and move on? Isn't this site is also intended to help others in the future?

Comment: What stopped you from commenting to the user the gist of what you posted here? "People have attempted to assist with your incomplete question and with your follow-on questions. Please ask a new question if you have a new question - following our guidelines (link to how to ask)"

Comment: There is **no** requirement for people to accept answers. And there shouldn't be. Demanding them to accept means they may very well accept a bad/incorrect answer, just to "follow the rules" (which are not even rules).

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, this site is intended to help others besides the user who asked the question. You should be trying to post an answer that will be useful to anyone with the same problem not just the OP.  Forcing an acceptance doesn't do anything, there are plenty of times the OP accepts incorrect answers.  I've seen plenty of occasions where a wrong answer has been accepted because the OP was pressured to accept something, that helps no one!

Comment: @Oded, I did ask him to post a new question. And they shouldn't accept incorrect answers. Only answers that they admit **themselves** that are correct. But whatever, I see there is no point as no one agrees with me here

Comment: @DavidArenburg When you post a feature request on Meta you have to be prepared for criticism of it when people don't agree with it.

Comment: @DavidArenburg requiring users to accept answers was gotten rid of a while ago, because it forced people to accept answers that didn't really solve their problem.

Comment: This can probably be marked as a duplicate of an already existing question, if anyone wants to dig around for a suitable canonical question.

Comment: @Cupcake, I'd actually be glad if you provide the duplicate cause I didn't find any and would love to see what people wrote there

Comment: @DavidArenburg just look around for questions or answers suggesting to make it harder for people to ask questions on [main]. Trust me, there's been a lot of talk about that sort of thing recently in the past month or two.

Comment: I say make it virtually impossible to ask a new question. Step 1) Remove the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: @user414076, thanks for the constructive comment

Comment: I'm serious, though. Heck, I upvoted this question *immediately* based on the title, but then had to take it back because of your suggestion 1.

Comment: @DavidArenburg A few related Meta discussions are [Low-rep users should not be able to ask questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253168/low-rep-users-should-not-be-able-to-ask-questions), [What effect would introducing a small barrier for new users to ask a question have on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252061/) and [Should signup on SO be closed for a while?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256396/should-signup-on-so-be-closed-for-a-while/256398#256398)

Comment: @Oded `They can only post a new question every 90 minutes. That's a maximum of 9 question in 10 hours. Not enough?` Not sure I agree with you 100% on your arithmetic there.

Comment: @DavidRobinson - frain bart. fixed - thanks

Comment: @Oded I like that you can edit hour long comments, why can't a non-moderator do that?

Comment: An Upvote at last...

Comment: @DavidArenburg A moderator can edit *any* comment from *any* user (including their own).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. There is no reason to require accepting of an answer.  None whatsoever.  Accepting answers has a very minimal benefit to the system.  Questions authors are given the privilege of informing the community and other readers what answer they feel is the "best", and to have that answer bumped to the top of the list.  They have no obligation to leverage this feature.  Attempting to force them to do so (something this community has extensive experience with) does **way** more harm than good.
2. To your required information:

   1. Questions *are* required to contain a title.  If you know of a way to automatically judge whether a title is "informative", I'd love to hear it.
   2. An example isn't always necessary for all questions.  Sometimes it is, sometimes it isn't.  Requiring information that isn't actually required is just confusing and causes way more problems than it solves.  If a question is missing an example that is necessary, in context, you can request one through a comment.  If the post is unanswerable without one, vote to close accordingly.  If you figure out how to judge whether a question has enough information to be answerable entirely automatically, again, I'd love to hear it.
   3. How do you intend to judge whether or not there is a "well defined question" automatically?  If you *can't* figure out what is being requested then you should be posting a comment to ask for clarification and voting to close.
   4. Not all questions are asking for code that produces a specific type of output, so this is not always necessary.
3. There is already a limit of questions per day.  It's a touch higher than 3, but the limit exists.  Tweaking them a bit is probably the only suggestion here that has some merit, and is worth looking into.

Comment: I will agree that it's hard for me to "automatically judge" but I think that the user should be informed that he has to make the title informative (examples could be provided to him) and that he has to provide sufficient information. Your solution suggest mainly to use comments. That what I do already, I'm tired writing 5 comments and waiting for responses for every single question. I feel like I'm wasting my time in vaine. My task is to help him code, not teach him english and grammar, neither to teach him how to post on SO. It's SO job to do that

Comment: @DavidArenburg They are *already* told all of those things.  Users are provided with a link to "how to ask" and required to confirm that they've read it before posting.  Virtually none ever do, and there's no real way to make them, but we try anyway.  There really aren't any options here other than having actual humans closing these types of questions.  Sure, it'd be nice if bad questions could just magically get closed all on their own.  If you find a way to do that, let me know.  Until then, we have to do it manually.

Comment: a way to "judge title" has been discussed at MSE: [How to save the world… One question title at a time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201940/how-to-save-the-world-one-question-title-at-a-time)

Comment: @gnat However they're all looking at ways of evaluating the quality of a title after it's posted, not ways of preventing someone from posting a question until they have a good title.  There's a pretty big difference between the two.

Comment: @Servy agree, there's a big difference. What is discussed at MSE looks like possibly doable and sensible, what is proposed here doesn't

Answer (score 3):

The correlation between new users and really bad quality posts is somewhat high in my experience, my advice is that they are presented the first time with actual examples of bad and good post, maybe letting them review (considering or not the vote, as is done in the review tests) one or two questions before posting their first one, this raises the new user attachment to the perceived community (probably), and in doing so it forces the perception of a site where actual people spend time for your real problems, so maybe you should apply a little of your time too.

I don't feel that forcing acceptance of agreements, or answers is the way to go, in any way, as already pointed out by others.

Comment: I actually gave up on that idea long ago (I posted this when I was barely a two months user myself). I don't really care anymore, as it seems that no else cares.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think that this perceived issue will become more and more raised as the site gets bigger, that's because I posted that advice.

Comment: @DRC The site is already big enough and people are even against any form of change let alone caring. Look at the amount of downvotes [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281012/why-does-stack-overflow-allow-such-rudeness-and-condescension-and-arrogance-from) is receiving.