# Why does Stack Overflow allow such rudeness and condescension and arrogance from posters?

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts, question-quality

ATM, anyone can easily open an account and ask annoying questions that :

- ask for piles of crappy code with single-letter var names, [i,j,k] array indices, no comments and 'do all my debugging for me' requests
- ask for a precis of the 36,000,000 results returned by Googling the title so that they have a unique answer for their assignment
- ask for complete system designs without documenting one solid requirement or constraint and with not a single line of code written
- are grossly-obvious homework question dumps
- are surely code copied directly from web pages or someone else's homework and don't work in isolation, together with a plaintive 'can anyone explain this code and fix it?'
- ask for help with fixing distributed systems from contributors who have been shown a dump of half the code, no environment, no server, no error messages/logs and no debugger, the implication being that SO contributors should spend a day recreating their crap in a useable form, only to find that the OP's router was misconfigured.
- are mega-dups because the poster could not be bothered to search SO first
- are straightforward Google-slave commands to do their research for them

  So, how to stop this 'rudeness and condescension and arrogance'?

I can only suggest more education before new account holders can post a question.  If it was much more difficult to open an account because prospective users had to read a longer, more extended tour, that would reduce the number of duplicate/puppet accounts and perhaps generate enough consideration towards SO contributors that they are treated as a valuable resource instead of a gang of slaves to be exploited to the fullest extent possible.

Comment: That wouldn't prevent anything. That kind of users still try to find a way to skip all and get to the question posting process.

Comment: Well played, OP.

Comment: I can enjoy the joke, but this is a joke at someone specific's expense. By posting this you *are* perpetuating the myth here that Stack Overflow tolerates outride rudeness (which we don't).

Comment: Charge a one-time fee of $0.01 or a similar, trivial amount for the privilege of asking questions, accepting credit card only (also grant that privilege to anybody earning 100/200 rep with answers). Extend question-ban to ban every account associated with that credit card, and blacklist the card number to disallow future account creation. Way harder to get a new credit card than a new OAuth ID. If the quality problem still persists, raise the price of asking questions.

Comment: @l4mpi That cuts off probably 90%+ of the crowd at SO, and I'm not even sure if the remaining 10% is a "higher quality" crowd. It's also USA-centered, as many people here in Europe don't even have credit cards (like many other places on Earth). I'd say it's a pretty terrible idea.

Comment: related: [why does stack overflow allow such rudeness and condescension and arrogance in its](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281009/why-does-stack-overflow-allow-such-rudeness-and-condescension-and-arrogance-in-i)

Comment: @orlp It's hardly USA-centered as I'm European. And there are services that allow you to register an online prepaid credit card for minimal fees. Furthermore, it wouldn't stop people from _answering_ questions, and simply earning the asking privilege this way. I'm also not even sure if cutting off 90% of question askers would be bad. Yes, it would be a radical change, will obviously never be implemented by SO, and there may be better ways to do it, but I do believe that a similar level of account identification (to prevent ban evasion etc) would be a top requirement for any future SE clones.

Comment: ...see also: [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/): "We feel that the world is awash in questions, but not answers. Answers are the real unit of work in any Q&A system. Therefore, the only logical thing to do is to maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers. If this means aggressively downvoting or closing unworthy and uninteresting questions, so be it. Without a community of people willing to _answer_ questions, it really doesn’t matter if there are questions at all, does it?"

Comment: @l4mpi I do not believe that ban evasion is a big issue. The issue is that the low-quality crowd is just large, not ban-evading. Generally this crowd is not nefarious, but either immature or uneducated. And whether or not you're from Europe is irrelevant anecdotal evidence changing nothing about the fact that requiring a credit card is an USA-centered model, as it's only safe to assume that someone in the USA has a credit card while in other regions of the world that assumption doesn't hold remotely as well.

Comment: @orlp it's hard with 600 chars only, and also getting somewhat off-topic, but of course requiring a credit card or other form of _hard_ identification would only be the first step (if you know anything that could realistically work, tell me). The second would be tuning the question ban threshold. And that many SO users might not have a credit card is IMO good. Asking questions is a privilege, if a user spends time to register an online credit card they will probably treat it better than if they get it for free. Accout creation _should_ be hard, asking on SO should not be the easiest option.

Comment: The _answerer(s)_ to be blamed too, especially rep-whores. If such questions are neglected, closed and deleted on spot; new users will learn from their mistakes.

Comment: @Sompuperoo stuffing more help and information in front of new users, as OP suggested, has also been discussed a thousand times, and is proven not to work - people don't read, especially the ones who should really do so. And my suggestion _is_ related to making it "much more difficult to open an account"; and furthermore making people more aware of the fact that asking is a privilege. I simply think giving a new user more pages to click through and not read is not increasing the difficulty at all.

Comment: Latest in: 'I have to do this program in C, but I don't know C programming'.  I mean, WTF?

Comment: @Jongware - exactly, it's just so easy to find the rubbish.  Finding a good question is like dumpster-diving for quarters.

Comment: I've mostly given up on it now. It's not SO's _fault_ and charging somebody's credit card isn't going to do jack (what a terrible idea!!) but it's the nature of the game once a community hits saturation point. We shouldn't have been so open, perhaps.

Comment: The canonical answer for meta questions like this is _"You don't have to read / answer such questions, vote accordingly and move along"_. Preventing the influx of crap hasn't been addressed as far as I know.

Comment: Preventing the influx of crap is being addressed massively, continuously, by the SE team. They're just not as willing to impose extremely draconian restrictions on asking as some of us would like to see

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Don't blame the problem. There is always a solution. But I too have given up on this due to SO staff's passive attitude towards this incredibly important issue.

Comment: @simonzack: They've done loads to try to combat it. It's not their fault the problem is intractible.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Are you recommending people to vote on a question without reading it?

Comment: @Lightness no, I am paraphrasing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's the passive attitude I'm talking about. Let's all blame the problem and all the posters instead. It's intractible anyway, right? Why should we *care* about an intractible problem?

Comment: How about disabling the 'Next' button until, say, 30 seconds have passed?

Comment: @simonzack: TIL identifying objective facts is "passive attitude". Seems you'd rather _ignore_ the facts and find somebody to blame just so that you're being "active" and "doing something". Yeah, that'll do it, son.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Now whos pulling "facts" out of thin air and just finding a problem to blame?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the actual idea behind the credit card thing is having a method of accurately tying accounts to people; and by doing so making it clear to users that their actions will be judged and can lead to a lifetime ban (also making this enforcable in the first place). I believe people won't bother to post crap if they know it will just lead to a ban. I'm aware credit cards are very suboptimal for many reasons (#1: they're not 1-1 related with people), but until all nations offer some sort of citizen OpenID it is probably the simplest and most available method of identification.

Comment: I think verification doesn't address the root of the problem - that bad behaviour is 'rewarded'. The overhead for posting is low, and you _might_ get an answer. If your 'bad question' is low hanging fruit, then someone can either: Downvote/close, or chip in a 10s answer that might be right, and might get some rep. 
Big and horrible questions don't have that as much, because the effort involved in feeding the 'help vampire'.

Comment: @l4mpi: a alternative for the _horrible_ credit card idea, would be a phone number. Pretty much everyone that asks questions on SO has a phone, compared to a minority owning a credit card. I personally wouldn't mind adding a phone as authentication factor, but I'm sure as hell not going to register a credit card that's going to cost me actual money, just to ask questions on SO. I'm sure there are other users with significant rep that agree.

Comment: @Cerbrus A phone number has almost the same problems though - I'd be more reluctant to share mine than the details for a prepaid credit card (which btw does not have to cost money), and new phone numbers are easy to acquire or even to borrow from non-programmer friends.

Comment: @l4mpi: That's absurd. Just because spending money you don't have is widespread in the USA doesn't mean it's widespread worldwide. Many, many people do not have credit cards. And what about those too young? We support accounts for 13 year olds. There is no problem tying accounts to people: there is a problem extracting useful posts from accounts.

Comment: Authentication by phone usually involves receiving a text containing some kind of verification code. That means you can't just use some else's number, you'll need to have access to their phones. People I know would ask _"Why don't you just use your own phone?"_...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Of course this also requires a stricter enforcement of quality standards. But tying accounts to people is the first step, and is not enforced currently. And I don't know what any of this has to do with spending money (or with USA, wtf?) - I don't propose charging people any significant amount. Feel free to propose better alternatives, as I said I can't think of any. And Cerbrus, the answer to "Why don't you use your own phone?" would probably be "Because they blocked me, it's so unfair. I just need yours to receive this one text message!". Probably works rather often.

Comment: @l4mpi: Only those who want to spend money they don't have own credit cards. Why do you feel you need to tie accounts to people? The only thing I can see that helping to prevent is spam accounts, and those are already dealt with incredibly efficiently.

Comment: _"Because they blocked me"_ Answer: _"Your problem, I'm not gonna get my phone tied to a site you got blocked from."How does a _credit card_ not have anything to do with spending money? With a phone number I at least know for sure someone with malicious intent can't just get at my money. Credit card number? Not quite as safe.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There are tons of services you _can't_ reasonably access without a credit card, and many others where it's very beneficial to use one over other means of payment. I mentioned _prepaid_ cards multiple times (you need to _send_ money to the card before you can use it). And if you tie accounts to people, and do so closely, and tell them about it, they might take warnings about "we'll ban you" more serious than when they register with any random gmail address that takes 5s to set up.

Comment: @l4mpi: You grossly underestimate the way question bans work. They're not just basic single-user account de-activations, y'know. As for "there are tons of services you _can't_ reasonably access without a credit card", that's just simply not true. In fact I can't think of _any_ right now. Could you give an example?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have no idea how they work internally (and I doubt you do as afaik that information is not public), but how could they realistically block someone with a new mail address and a new IP (which is often only a question of resetting ones router)? I can't think of any way. And there have been instances of users openly bragging about circumventing bans on SO and meta. I don't have any data, obviously, but it could be just as likely that you grossly overestimate the way the bans work. Re credit card only services, google wallet (they don't take maestro), intl. purchrases, etc

Comment: @l4mpi: "that information is not public" Spend just five minutes searching on meta, mate. Google Wallet is only available in the US so I have no idea about that anyway, but I make international purchases with my debit card _all the time_. Again, you are applying an extreme US bias to your argument. Just because your American shops only take credit card (which I doubt) for international purchases doesn't mean that's true of any of the rest of the world, which is what I said in the first place.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit all I can find is information about the "anti-recidivism system" which is afaik for _deleted_ accounts that are registered again with the _same_ OpenID (again, how could they notice that it's the same physical person if another IP, OpenID and possibly PC are used), and multiple statements that "To avoid bypassing the filter its internal rules are a secret". If there is any more information I'd appreciate a link. And google wallet is (was, at least) needed for android app purchrases, and is of course available outside of USA, and I'll say it again, I'm from Europe...

Comment: @l4mpi: There is loads about how question bans are handled. Some of it can be found on the canonical FAQ that was written explaining to people who have been banned what they can try, and what is pointless trying. I'm not going to spend my own time tracking it down for you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the question ban FAQ is what I quoted above. And I can't be bothered to search things to prove _your_ arguments either - the burden of proof that there is, as you say, anything in place to stop this is on you. But as long as you obviously don't even bother to carefully read through the previous conversation (for the record, I've had to say twice now that I'm _not_ from the US), I don't think this discussion is going anywhere.

Comment: @l4mpi: That you're not from the US makes it _even weirder_ that your argument has such a strong US bias. Like invoking Google Wallet as an example, which is a US-only service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67557/discussion-between-l4mpi-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit some evidence that it seems to be very simple to evade a ban by creating a new account: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283365/why-all-my-accounts-has-been-blocked-from-asking-questions - the user says they create a new account once they're banned (and then get banned again due to bad questions); this has apparently happened at least 5 times; their current account has 11 non-deleted questions. This seems to me as if any measures in place to stop people from evading a ban are completely useless. And users like this pop up regularily, so it's not an isolated case.

Comment: Whats wrong with using i,j,k for indices...

Answer (score 24):

Part of what makes SO attractive is its accessibility. Anyone can get started and get some use out of the site.

Some of this does promote laziness, but y'know—not every new poster is lazy. It's just more obvious when it does happen.

We can:

- Downvote a bad question
- Close a bad question

And maybe the [triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage) can delay and otherwise prevent bad questions from offending the eye.

But pretty fundamentally, if someone asks a bad question, and gets an answer, they'll do it again. I think that's the core problem, really—people will answer because that's rewarded (with rep) where closing/downvoting, etc., doesn't.

*Shrug*. How about if—instead of what you suggest—SO implements a 'correct choice' bonus. E.g., if you downvote or vote to close, if the question *is* closed or deleted (maybe a bonus for retracting a DV on a 'fixed' question?) ... you get some rep for it.

Mostly, SO does gamification. Actions are encouraged by reputation points. It's not too much a surprise that people do things that optimise their scoring in favour of following ideology.

Comment: The "correct choice" bonus is an interesting idea!

Comment: (Have not spotted the 'related' post. Oh well, I stand by my opinion, even if I didn't 'get it' :)

Comment: Here is an example of this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27606667/2887133  .... How is possible that a User with such high rep answer a reallly bad answer that not shows any effort ? This encourage other new and low users to make really bad questions and they still get answers

Comment: Partly because you do get to read between the lines, and can guess what someone _meant_ when they ask. And partly because answers get rep, and closes/downvotes don't.

Comment: @Danko [that's an old rotten romance](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MW9QR.gif)

Comment: @Danko It's not that bad a question, in my opinion. It's not a particularly good question, but it's clear what the OP is asking, and although it's not immediately apparent, the OP does actually show at least some effort: the OP is looking for a specific effect, and the OP has figured out which two properties to combine without any help, and is merely having trouble actually combining them.

Comment: There is a slope, IMO. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445330/extract-substring-from-string-time-from-ping-reply-in-c-using-string-library) I answered to a particularly "bad" (too broad) question -- but only *after* a discussion in the comments and an acknowledgement from the OP those comments were helpful.

Comment: @hvd it's clear but to fit SO ... he must show some effort to solve the problem there is no code at all at least have he tried combine the properties? It's just like hey I want this layout maybe can be this way "code that for me"

Comment: Maybe we shouldn't give any rep for answers to negative-score questions so that there is less incentive answering such crap.

Comment: @Danko I guess I'm assuming that if the OP there already figured out that those two properties are the ones to combine, and testing whether that works is trivial, then the OP did probably do that already. It would be better to have shown the results of that, but I don't see a reason for assuming the OP didn't try it. Now, if merely combining those two properties *worked*, then I'd certainly agree with you.

Comment: @AndréDaniel: Then there goes (part of) the incentive to try to get a reversal badge.

Comment: Let the reversal badge go to hell with all the people who spoon feed help vampires. It's only one badge, we have lots of them. Gamification should only encourage good content, if we encourage answering bad questions then we also encourage posting these questions.

Comment: "if someone asks a bad question, and gets an answer, they'll do it again." this needs to be in **bold**

Comment: @AndréDaniel: So, just because someone got a downvote for no apparent reason we should discourage people from answering?

Comment: @Cerbrus a good question will always have more upvotes to cancel the downvotes.

Comment: The "correct choice" bonus is broken because you cannot say that your choice was "correct" just because five other people agreed with you.

Comment: @AndréDaniel: I've seen plenty of decent questions that get a random downvote. I've seen plenty of _good_ questions that haven't gotten any votes at all.
What happens if someone downvotes a question that has a answer already? You can't reward / punish someone for the voting behavour of other people on posts other than their own.

Comment: @Cerbrus maybe we can start by being less aggressive and removing answer rep only when the question is at -2 or lower, to account for the unfortunate "accidental" downvote.

Comment: probably hold all reputation from answers until a question is established to be a "good" question (by it passing the triage queue), according to the SO standards?

Comment: 5 people agreeing doesn't necessarily mean you're right, that's true. But an upvoted answer (giving rep) isn't necessarily right either. It's just _on balance_ several people have thought it was.

Comment: @AwalGarg I think that for a start, SE team could put _a bit_ more effort into finding out [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077/839601)

Comment: I don't think it's the auto delete per-se. It's the half-life of a poor question. It takes a bit of time to disappear, and in the meantime, the help vampire may have had their 'fix'.

Answer (score 3):

This question seems, ironically, like a good example of the fact that even long-time,  high-rep users can ask questions which aren't completely thought through. All of the things you're describing (asking broadly for all debugging, asking duplicate questions, asking a question without clear requirements, etc etc) are all things that **close reasons exist for already**.

This question seems to conflate "allowing" something to be posted with allowing it on the site - there's no way to make sure that nobody can ever post any low quality question,  but **that's far from meaning that we "allow" those types of questions**. There's very robust community moderation in force which deals with these kinds of low-quality posts from both new users and old.

Comment: There was an earlier post that accused contributors of 'rudeness and condescension and arrogance'.  After I had typed out a suitably scathing reply, the question had been closed, so I copy/pasted to a new question and swapped source and destination.  It might be a dup but I was not going to let that lie without an immedate reply.

Comment: That seems rather petty, and still doesn't address the fact that your post isn't clear about what you're actually proposing and the complaints you're describing are all addressed by the existing community moderation system. If anything, this is like going "condescending and arrogant? *I'll* show **you** condescention and arrogance!".

Comment: Well, maybe.  If someone hits me, I hit them back.