# An ancient popular question has been hijacked, what can we do now?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, accepted-answer

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform) *circa* '10 was recently [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11418273) bringing a whole new extended meaning to it. The edited question is now out of context regarding some other questions that link to it, esp. [Android front camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098729/android-front-camera).

<s>Worse, the same [editor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5059838/bedbad) posted a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35648069/192373) to this question, which is both irrelevant for the original question, and also is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform#comment74953032_35648069).</s>

The question has been protected by Community♦ since Jul 15 '11, but this protection did not prevent hijacking. Unfortunately, the TS abandoned the question and the whole SO site quite a while ago, and neither a [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4135068/192373) nor the most upvoted *extended* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4767832/192373) can be 'accepted' through normal procedure.

I believe this is an example of abuse of SO procedures, and we should find a way to improve them.

I agree that discussion of whether a new answer was "wrong" or "well-worked out" is out of scope here.

Generally speaking, adding an answer "Please note that if you have a newer system, you should do this or that" to the old question is legitimate. If the question were not abandoned, it could even be accepted. Unfortunately, this question was abandoned immediately upon posting.

I believe that the due process to face the changing reality of public APIs is to create a separate question, like *[Android camera android.hardware.Camera deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065930/android-camera-android-hardware-camera-deprecated)* an answers therein. A question ***how do I open "front camera" now that android.hardware.Camera is deprecated*** is legitimate, IMHO, while extending a question that referred to Android 2.2 is not.

Comment: I don't really see how it has been hijacked? Where did the meaning change?

Comment: @Bart the original question was posted for Android 2.2 which had no official uniform way of addressing the front camera. The edit by bedbad was misleading. The information can be found in the official docs he referenced in his edit. It is nice to introduce a good question and even to provide an answer to it; it's OK to link to older questions. But here the old question was hijacked for the whole new context of API 21, etc.

Comment: Please don't start an [edit war](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15681204/revisions) Your edit is not acceptable in any way. If you think an answer is wrong, downvote or comment.

Comment: @ayhan please note that the edit has nothing to do with the discussion in this topic. The concept of badge disclaimer on top was supported by Community https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311430/192373

Comment: I understand that you and @Clive are fighting each other by deleting the badge.

Comment: No one's fighting, I just rolled back what I thought I knew to be a bad edit. As I said on the post, I wasn't aware the upvoted answer in that linked meta post had become policy, so I flagged for a mod to deal with it instead. Again, if you want to re-instate your edit before that happens so the mod has it right in front of them to make a decision, I encourage that.

Comment: I really don't care to re-instate the banner again, it is clearly seen in the revision history, and I also added exactly same banner to few other answers. If I understand correctly, neither **Clive** or **ayhan** are active in the field of Android, and specifically [android-camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-camera), so your reactions are more based on common sense, rather than domain-specific knowledge. The technical issue behind this is not trivial, and was described in a separate [meta-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311425).

Comment: "Oh look! Lots of green! This guy is hijacking the question!" (most of the edit was adding links, and being more clear on the meaning)

Comment: You don't need domain-specific knowledge to know the rules and etiquette of the site @AlexCohn. It could be the most technically difficult issue mankind has ever come up against, still doesn't mean anyone should be editing meta info into a post. It's locked now to prevent it happening again, so we can safely infer the somewhat-upvoted answer in the linked meta post is definitely not policy

Comment: @Braiam The original question was asked when neither of the added links existed.

Comment: @Clive, if you have something to say about https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311425, you are welcome to post an answer there. That question is not locked, as far as I know.

Comment: I don't @AlexCohn. If any policy ever comes out of it I'll be happy to conform to it. Until then I'll stick with existing policy

Comment: And? Are we supposed to never modify any post? Isn't what forums and blogs are and we set forth to fix? By making all post being able to be collaboratively edited and improved?

Comment: @Braiam My position is stated in **Update #2** above. You can and should improve questions, but not *change* their meaning, especially if the question is abandoned and the OP is not there to approve your improvement.

Comment: Whatever else you do **do not deface answers you think are wrong**. I've had to lock that post to prevent you from putting your stamp on it. Don't do that again.

Comment: You also appear to misunderstand what 'protection' does for a post, and why we have the feature. See the [help center guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions): *Questions should be protected when they are garnering lots of views and newbies are adding "me too!", "thanks!" and possibly even spam non-answers.*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters could you please propose your opinion on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311425?

Comment: @AlexCohn: you really think that picking the wrong camera is as harmful as a SQL injection? Not that I agree with that answer, mind you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are right; the developers who copy/paste the wrong solution for front camera don't open privacy backdoors for their innocent customers; they harm mainly themselves, and if you believe that our professional standing can be protected by keeping traps of crashing or misbehaving code ready for copy/paste - let it be so.

Comment: @AlexCohn, this is a seriously misgueded use of your editor powers: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25447178/revisions Adding your flair to answers, really???

Comment: @brasofilo we've established that's not desirable (see Martijn's comment above), do feel free to roll them back

Comment: Funny how the question title is entirely accurate. Just not in the way OP meant it.

Comment: Hey, @MartijnPieters maybe you can find time to propose your solution to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311425? In the meanwhile, I come across more answers that continue to spread bad practice: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17117023/192373 https://stackoverflow.com/q/42113189/192373 https://stackoverflow.com/a/29539597/192373
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44755915/192373

Answer (score 9):

Please stop offending people by marking their well-worked out answers as "**bad**" and "**worst**".

1. My answer was posted months before my editing, so he is lying by saying "A question circa '10 was recently edited bringing a whole new extended meaning to it" and "Worse, the same editor posted a new answer to this question".
2. My editing did not "add whole new extended meaning to it". *I rolled back the editing by the user peak (edited Feb 26 '16 at 13:12) which completely changed the original years-old question.* - I agree that's not the point(I simply forgot my previous edit), but my first edit was only addition to original text for clarification of the original question, because "frontal" and "back", that are subject of the question, are values of location on the hardware.
3. My answer is the only new answer addressing recent changes in Android Camera API to Camera2 and quoting official Android sources that say the new Camera API should be used instead of old one. It therefore can't be irrelevant, since all old answers reference old API.
4. Alex Cohn didn't read my answer and claims that it has a completely (exactly) contrary meaning to what it contains.

I believe the offender has personal issues with me outside of SO and it should not be shown here. I call the TS to delete his offensive comments such as "bad", "worst", "worse" etc. - such personal language should not be used in constructive discussions at all.

Comment: 3. wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42158252/192373

Comment: 2. wrong: user @peak [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2779002/3) your [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2779002/2) (both on Feb 26, '16)

Comment: If anyone thinks an answer is wrong/poor/bad, they are free to state so. There isn't anything problematic about that. You then have the opportunity to calmly explain why it is not.

Comment: @Daedalus: the original question was posted for Android 2.2 which had no official uniform way of addressing the front camera. The [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2779002/2) by [bedbad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5059838/bedbad) was misleading. The information *can be found in the official docs he referenced in his edit*. It is nice to introduce a good question and even to provide an answer to it; it's OK to link to older questions. But here the old question was hijacked for the whole new context of API 21, *etc.*

Comment: @AlexCohn That reply does not appear to address my comment.  Please do not @ alert me if you aren't going to actually respond to me.

Comment: I may have forgotten that initial edit, so the edit of the @peak edit by me wasn't rollback to the original answer. That's true. I agree to withdraw that particular point.

Comment: 1. wrong: the answer was published on Feb 26 '16 at 9:35; the question edit was suggested on Feb 26 '16 at 13:12. This is hardly 'months'.

Comment: @AlexCohn Please explain specifically how 3. is wrong.

Comment: @Daedalus, here is what's wrong with 3: **a)** only new answer addressing recent changes in Android Camera API to Camera2: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42158252/192373  also shows how to choose front camera with camera2 API. ***But*** the code snippet in http://stackoverflow.com/a/42158252/192373 is correct, while http://stackoverflow.com/a/35648069/192373 does not provide code that can answer the (edited) question.

Comment: **b)** *quoting official Android sources that say the new Camera API should be used instead of old one* is not in the scope of this question, even after the edit. There is a separate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065930/android-camera-android-hardware-camera-deprecated) about it, with detailed and well-expressed answer. It is OK to link to another question, add another answer... But I don't agree that having added this reference to Android docs makes this answer better.

Comment: @AlexCohn Thank you for addressing my comment finally; somehow I missed the 'only new' part of the 3 post.  As such, I am deleting my prior comment.

Comment: No, It's wrong. Read my answer please! Camera_Facing in any API is just a constant: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#LENS_FACING_FRONT

Comment: **c)** My claim was that the answer was *irrelevant for the original question*. This question has a few "siblings" ([How to use Front Facing Camera on Samsung Galaxy S](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241292), [Can I take a picture using the front camera on Samsung Galaxy Tab (Android 2.2) ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756998), ...): all these questions were posted more or less at the same time, when Android 2.2 devices with front cameras started to appear, but official API was not yet available.

Comment: Therefore NO Code can determine whether that constant true or not. It's just getting device by this id from the hardware. No code can determine **where the camera is actually located** on the hardware, - not even any software, even Android software. That's exactly what I was trying to point out in my answer. Answers with code snippets, can't be accurate.

Comment: **d)** but in this topic, I would rather discuss the question edit, not how wrong the answer is, or why

Comment: "@Daedalus, here is what's wrong with 3: a) only new answer addressing recent changes in Android Camera API to Camera2: stackoverflow.com/a/42158252/192373 also shows how to choose front camera with camera2 API. But the code snippet in stackoverflow.com/a/42158252/192373 is correct, while stackoverflow.com/a/35648069/192373 does not provide code that can answer the (edited) question. "
1)The code is misleading, and therefore can't be called just correct
2)That's precisely the reason why didn't include any code in my answer.

Comment: "but in this topic, I would rather discuss the question edit, not how wrong the answer is, or why "
It's you comment higher, not mine.

Comment: on API and relevance (3) Andoid API 21 was released November 12, 2014 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history That answer is from 2010. I believe it was edited later then I saw, but it definitely not referred to original API itself.